# FOSUserBundle and ACL Business Role

Tags: symfony, yii, acl, fosuserbundle

I started to learn Symfony 2 this weekend. I faced no problem, as the framework is well documented in my opinion.

I'm using FOSUserBundle package for ACL. I'm wondering if it's possible to make it similar to Yii framework:

```
$bizRule='return Yii::app()->user->id==$params["post"]->authID;';
$task=$auth->createTask('updateOwnPost','update a post by author himself',$bizRule);
$task->addChild('updatePost');
```

You may see all details on the snippet above.

How can I achieve something similar with Symfony 2? Is this possible?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to be able to restrict editing/updating of a post to the author of that post? I'm not familiar with Yii, so I'm kind of taking a shot in the dark here.

Comment: @Problematic - Exactly. Yii ACL approach allows you to provide a business rule (as shown in the snippet in my question). It checks automatically if logged user id equals authID - or any other column - of the post that is selected from database). Do you know about similar functionality in Symfony 2?

Answer (score 22):

Symfony2 has an [ACL system](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html) out of the box that will do this. I'm including the relevant code for the sake of completeness (modified for `Post` instead of `Comment` as is in the documentation):

```
public function addPostAction()
{
    $post = new Post();

    // setup $form, and bind data
    // ...

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $entityManager = $this->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
        $entityManager->persist($post);
        $entityManager->flush();

        // creating the ACL
        $aclProvider = $this->get('security.acl.provider');
        $objectIdentity = ObjectIdentity::fromDomainObject($post);
        $acl = $aclProvider->createAcl($objectIdentity);

        // retrieving the security identity of the currently logged-in user
        $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');
        $user = $securityContext->getToken()->getUser();
        $securityIdentity = UserSecurityIdentity::fromAccount($user);

        // grant owner access
        $acl->insertObjectAce($securityIdentity, MaskBuilder::MASK_OWNER);
        $aclProvider->updateAcl($acl);
    }
}
```

Essentially, you're giving the currently logged in user ownership of the Post entity (which includes edit permissions). And then to check if the current user has permission to edit:

```
public function editPostAction(Post $post)
{
    $securityContext = $this->get('security.context');

    // check for edit access
    if (false === $securityContext->isGranted('EDIT', $post))
    {
        throw new AccessDeniedException();
    }

    // retrieve actual post object, and do your editing here
    // ...
}
```

I *highly* recommend that you read through both the [Access Control List](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html) and [Advanced ACL Concepts](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl_advanced.html) cookbook recipes for more information. The actual creation of ACLs as shown above is extremely verbose, and I have been working on an [open-source ACL manager](https://github.com/Problematic/AclManagerBundle) to ease the pain... it "kind of works;" it's early beta and needs a lot of love, so use at your own risk.

Comment: If my answer has helped you, please feel free to upvote and accept it using the arrows and checkmark near the top of the answer. Thanks.