# Manage Roles and Assign Permissions to Roles - Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, permissions, fosuserbundle, acl

I'm building an Admin panel in Symfony 3 based on Roles & Permissions. Each admin will be assigned a role(or multiple roles) and then he will be able to do things based on the permissions assigned to that role.

---

To give you an idea, here's an example:

- Admin panel has the functionality to add users, edit users and delete users.
- I created a role: `USER_MANAGEMENT_WITHOUT_DELETE` which has permission to `user_create` and `user_edit`.
- I created `USER_MANAGEMENT_WITH_DELETE` role which has permission to `user_create`, `user_edit` and `user_delete`
- So now, admin with role `USER_MANAGEMENT_WITH_DELETE` can `add`, `edit` and `delete` the users where as admin with role `USER_MANAGEMENT_WITHOUT_DELETE` can only `add` and `edit` users but cannot delete them.

---

I searched and found out about [FOSUserBundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSUserBundle/index.html) and  [ACL](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html). Some [recommended ACL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7002637/fosuserbundle-and-acl-business-role) while others say it's better to [use FOSUserBunder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13842571/symfony-2-checking-action-permission-with-roles-and-groups)

I also read the documentation of FOSUserBunder and how it store Roles in `roles` column, something like `a:1:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";}`, but there is nothing mentioned about permissions. So here are my queries:

1. I'm confused between the two. Which one should i use?
2. If i use `FOSUserBunder`, how to manage permissions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Roles are not specific tu FOSUserBundle. They are in Symfony.

[ACLs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/acl.html) are more complex than using roles. So I would suggest to use roles.

From the Symfony documentation :
Alternatives to ACLs

> Using ACL's isn't trivial, and for simpler use cases, it may be
>   overkill. If your permission logic could be described by just writing
>   some code (e.g. to check if a Blog is owned by the current User), then
>   consider using voters. A voter is passed the object being voted on,
>   which you can use to make complex decisions and effectively implement
>   your own ACL. Enforcing authorization (e.g. the isGranted part) will
>   look similar to what you see in this entry, but your voter class will
>   handle the logic behind the scenes, instead of the ACL system.

To deal with 'permissions', I would sugget to use [Voters](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/voters.html) :

First of all create a voter like this :

Configuration :

```
# app/config/services.yml
services:
    app.user_permissions:
        class: AppBundle\Voters\UserPermissionsVoter
        arguments: ['@security.access.decision_manager']
        tags:
            - { name: security.voter }
        public: false
```

And the class :

```
namespace AppBundle\Voters;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\Voter\Voter;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\UserInterface;

class UserPermissionsVoter extends Voter
{
    const USER_CREATE = 'user_create';
    const USER_EDIT = 'user_edit';
    const USER_DELETE = 'user_delete';

    private $decisionManager;

    public function __construct($decisionManager)
    {
        $this->decisionManager = $decisionManager;
    }

    protected function supports($attribute, $object)
    {    
        if (!in_array($attribute, array(self::USER_CREATE,self::USER_EDIT,self::USER_DELETE))) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    protected function voteOnAttribute($attribute, $object, TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $token->getUser();

        if (!$user instanceof UserInterface) {
            return false;
        }

        switch($attribute) {
            case self::USER_CREATE:
                if ($this->decisionManager->decide($token, array('ROLE_USER_MANAGEMENT_WITH_DELETE'))
                    || $this->decisionManager->decide($token, array('USER_MANAGEMENT_WITHOUT_DELETE'))
                ){
                    return true;
                }
            break;
            case self::USER_EDIT:
                // ...
            break;
            case self::USER_DELETE:
                // ...
            break;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

Then you can check for permission in your controller :

```
userCreateAction()
{
    if(!$this->isGranted('user_create')){throw $this->createAccessDeniedException('You are not allowed to create an user.');}

    // next steps ...
}
```