# How to check if another controller "is granted" for the logged-in user?

Tags: php, symfony, authorization

e.g. I have a Show Controller for my Categories, and there is an "actions" property I want to provide the frontend with the list of actions that the current logged-in user can do on this entity (e.g. `["edit", "delete"]`).

In the backend I want to simply give a list of Controllers (since I use `__invoke`, just passing the class name should be enough: e.g. `["edit" => CategoryEditController::class, "delete" => CategoryDeleteController::class]`) to a function which tells me whether that controller is accessible for the user or not (e.g. `["edit" => true, "delete" => false]`)

I haven't figured out yet how I can check another class's `IsGranted` which is the crucial issue I'm facing. Does anyone have an idea?

Also need to consider, IsGranted could not just be a string but an expression and also contain a subject. The `security.yaml` could also have constraints not directly represented in the IsGranted.

Comment: Please check symfony voter it might help you https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html

Comment: I don't understand your question. Have you looked into API Platform?

Comment: @RaviDamasiya wouldn't the voters just to have additional checks for the current request, nothing I could use to manually check other controllers?

Comment: @StephanVierkant hmm I don't know if following explains: I need to check if a given controller/function can be accessed by the user currently logged in, by making use of the IsGranted attribute (or maybe there is a better method) on that controller/function/security.yaml

Comment: *"I haven't figured out yet how I can check another class's IsGranted"* That's not how that works, IsGranted is just checking the role/status of a user that is currently logged in. Maybe you can create different roles for your users, depending if they can edit, delete, create etc.. Maybe i am misunderstanding you?

Comment: @Bossman ok maybe IsGranted is the wrong word. Since technically there is the AuthenicationChecker->isGranted, that however wouldn't consider if the security.yaml is blocking a user. I merely need to say, ok here is my category (model), and following are the actions you can do on this entity (edit, delete), how do I figure out whether the user can do those actions, by somehow using the information already available on the controller (IsGranted) of those actions and the security.yaml (access_map).

Comment: To do what you want you can using roles and permissions via a custom voter, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38566286/3585143) is a good example and should move you forward.